# Getting error "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes....."

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've looked around other SO questions and can't quite find one similar to my issue, so here goes.

I created a react-redux site using Microsoft JavaScript Services. I wanted to manually add a component to the project, just so I can get my head around how things worked.

I created a new `.tsx` file with my component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class ListingTitle extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col desktop-two-thirds tablet-half mobile-full">
                    <p id="carName" className="car-details-wrapper__car-name">
                        Fiat
                    </p>
                    <p className="car-details-wrapper__car-spec">
                        500
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ListingTitle />,
    document.getElementById("react-listing-title")
);
```

In an ASP.NET MVC view file, I have a div named "react-listing-title" which I hoped this React component would inject itself into.

The problem is that the webpack step gives me this error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/ListingTitle.tsx:23:5
>           TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }...'.
>         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly>'.
>           Property 'match' is missing in type '{}'.

I tried altering the class declaration like this:

```
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

export default class ListingTitle extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>
```

But that did not work either. The template project does comes with a router config, which I manually added my custom page into:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Counter from "./components/Counter";
import FetchData from "./components/FetchData";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import { Layout } from "./components/Layout";
import ListingTitle from "./components/ListingTitle";

export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
    <Route path="/counter" component={ Counter } />
    <Route path="/Details" component={ListingTitle} /> <-- This is my component
    <Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={ FetchData } />
</Layout>;
```

I'm very new to this, so any help would be appreciated.